# Webbrowser is not showing the updated version of a txt file but opening a new browser shows correct file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm experimenting with PHP together with Ajax and JQuery to make a site where I can write to a text file and then have the site load the textfile's contents into a div.

This is the JQuery code I'm using.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#text").load("storydoc.txt");
    }, 2000);
});
```

And here is the PHP together with the relevant HTML.

```
<div id="text">
</div>
<form id="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
    <input id="wordinput" class="input" type="text" name="word" maxlength="30"></input>
    <input id="submit" class="hidden" type="submit" name="submit"></input>
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $word = " " . $_POST['word'];
        $ret = file_put_contents('text.txt', $word, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        if($ret === false) {
            die("There was an error writing this file");
        }
    }
?>
```

So what it does is it lets the user write to "text.txt" using #wordinput and than updates #text with .load() to show the new updated text from "text.txt". This text can then be seen and written to by other users as well.

The problem I'm having is that the text file can show different contents on different browsers. If I for example open up the site in Firefox and write something to the text.file, it won't show. Even if I go to the file itself inside the cPanel file manager it still shows the text as it were when I got on the site. If I then open up Chrome and go to the site there, it will show the new updated text on both the site and file manager. Writing more words also instantly shows on the site in Chrome. Meanwhile Firefox is still showing the same outdated textfile contents even after refreshing. After this it works perfectly on all browsers but the one who first opened up the file first. Then if you leave the text file unedited for some time I get the same problem again, having to switch browser.

It works the same way the other way around, starting with Chrome, so I don't think it has anything to do with a specific webbrowser. To me it seems like the browser who first opens up "text.txt" saves a copy of it and only uses that one from there on out, and I have no clue how to solve it.

Any solutions or ideas are welcomed! Thank you in advance!

Comment: its cached, you can add a `GET` string to it like `storydoc.txt?v=1` and it should load correctly

Comment: @cmorrissey Haha, I knew it would be something simple like that. Thanks a lot, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Append a time string to the title of the file in the load statement to prevent caching -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var ms = (new Date).getTime(); // epoch time
        $("#text").load("storydoc.txt?ms=" + ms ); // add query string
    }, 2000);
});
```

The added string is inconsequential to the actual file but will have the affect of making the request 'new' each time because the added time string will be different and there will not be a copy in the cache.

Comment: You dah King, Sam ;-)

Comment: *Just the prince talking to the king Ralph* ;-) @Fred-ii-