# Can't refresh one specific div after ajax load (MVC system)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I already checked all others answers from that questions, but no one seems to work.

He's my problem, I try to reload a div where I got a php variable.
I got MVC system, so i can't call other files when i want.
My controller doesn't receive arguments from ajax call ($_POST and $_FILES are not isset).
When I try to do other stuff after ajax call, it works (example: unlink a file)

```
<?php 
    $test = 'lksd';
      ...
    if( some conditions )
      {
         $test= 'piof';
         unlink(../images/myImage.jpg);
      } 
  ?>
    ...
<div id="test">
   <?php
     echo $test;
   ?>
 </div>
```

And  my ajax call is in a jquery plugin (http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

I found where i can do my stuff, and then i call this function:

```
$('#test').load(window.location + "#test");
```

My div doesn't refresh but my file is deleted, if you have any idea of what can i do to solve this problem...

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Webbrowser is not showing the updated version of a txt file but opening a new browser shows correct file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653953/webbrowser-is-not-showing-the-updated-version-of-a-txt-file-but-opening-a-new-br)

Comment: I tried, it did not solve my problem, still got the old value of $test in my div

Comment: It worked for me, are there any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: No error in my brower's console

Comment: Are you trying to load something from the file you have open into the file you have open?

Comment: i don't get what you mean. What i do: i load my main page php, and in this  page i have a modal with a dropzone event. This dropzone event is managed by the plugin, including ajax request ( xml http request ). I included in this plugin a function to load my div test. I don't have any opened file except this js, who copy files dropped into a directory on my computer.

Comment: main.php makes a request to which file?

Comment: to itself, i have all requests on the same page. Like i said, i tried with another thing like "unlink('file.png')", it works

Comment: Do you have duplicate id's? Is `test` the id of more than one element?

Comment: Of course, i just checked again, he's the only one.

Comment: You may be creating a race condition because you're trying to load `#test` into `#test`. Doing that doesn't make much sense in the first place.

Comment: So can we load the HTML content of a div ? Or maybe try to load #test in #test_2 in js ?

Comment: You can load anything, but it looks like you have created a condition here where `#test` is trying to overwrite itself, since it is all in the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Create the PHP detail you want to stand alone. Call it something like getDetail.php:

```
<?php 
   $test = 'lksd';
   ...
   if( some conditions ) {
       $test= 'piof';
   }
   echo $test;
?>
```

In your page, you can now load that content at any time:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="test">
</div>
<a href="#" id="reloadDetail">Reload</a>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").load("getDetal.php");
    $("#reloadDetail").click(function(){
        $("#test").load("getDetail.php");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't try it tonight, i'll do it tomorrow :) thanks for the proposal :)
I've already a file that stand alone, i'm in a mvc like system, but i did'nt put the $_POST things in it :/

Comment: I tried this: i created a new file, with my code.
I included this file on my html, the echo and image thing work.
But i can't reload, due to my mvc system, who prints error 404 controller doesn't exist

Comment: It sounds like there is a lot missing from your original question. I would encourage you to edit it and add more details of what is actually happening.

Comment: Did it :) I don't really know what's going on, and i can't put all my code, would be so long... so i tried to summarize

Comment: IF my answer was helpful or addressed your question, please check it our just upvote it.