# Loading Chart connected to mysql without refreshing page using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, charts

I am new here. I have problem with my program.

The client wants a chart to load all data upon opening of the page then change the chart's value if the user typed on the query input box that is according to barangay only.

Below are my codes.

The following codes makes my form and its fields together with an image where my chart will be posted.

```
<form id="frmProtection" name="frmProtection" action="#" method="post" class="center">
    <table class="center">
        <tr>
            <td class="searchBox">
                <input list="brgy" id="searcher" name="filterBRGY" placeholder="Type Barangay..." autocomplete="off"/><br><br>
                <?php    
                  $query="SELECT barangay FROM  `brgy`";
                  $result=mysqli_query($con,$query)or die("Couldn't execute query.");
                  $log=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                ?>
                  <datalist id='brgy'>
                    <option value="<?php 
                                  echo $log['barangay'];
                                  ?>">
                    <?php 
                      while($log=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $log['barangay']; ?>">
                    <?php 
                      }
                    ?>
                  </datalist>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input onclick = "subForm(); return false;" type="submit" name="btnSub" id="btnSub" value="Generate Report"/>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<div class="container">
    <table class="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img id="protBar" width="500" height="200" alt="Child Protection Per Age Level - Numerical">
            </td>
            <td>
                <!--<img src="protectionPie.php" width="500" height="200" alt="Child Protection Per Age Level - Percentage">-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

--- In here is my javascript code that calls the php file protectionBar.php which generates my chart depending on the user's input.

```
<script>
function subForm()
{
    $(document).ready(function()
{
     $('#btnSub').click(function(e)
    {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var id = $("#searcher").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'charts/protectionBar.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "html",
            data: { id: id },
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#protBar').attr('src', data);

            }

        })
    });
 });
}
```

**Edits**

**Sorry for not posting my question. 
Here's what happens to my codes.
When the I enter a text in my search input box and click the submit button at first attempt, the chart is loaded perfectly. However, if I enter again on the search box for another attempt then click again the button, the chart is not loaded. No change happened and I don't know what's happening. Sorry, but novice at jQuery. I think, I'm lacking codes in my jQuery but I don't know what it is.**

***ANOTHER EDIT
The following code is what protectionBar.php does.***

```
<?php
/* Include all the classes -these are classes from pChart*/
include("class/pDraw.class.php");
include("class/pImage.class.php");
include("class/pData.class.php");
//this is where my connection properties goes
include('../config.inc.php');

/* Creating my dataset object */
$myData = new pData();

/* Build the query that will returns the data to graph */
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $idVar = $_POST['id'];
    $str = "SELECT TA.childNumber, TA.ageGroup, TA.totalAbused,CI.brgy FROM `totalabused` TA
            INNER JOIN `child_information` CI ON CI.childNumber=TA.childNumber
     WHERE CI.brgy LIKE '%".$idVar."%'";
}
else {
    $str = "SELECT childNumber, ageGroup, totalAbused FROM `totalabused`";

}

$result=mysqli_query($con,$str) or die("Couldn't execute query.");

//initializing my variables for charting
$abused_6_8=0;
$abused_9_11=0;
$abused_12_14=0;
$abused_15_17=0;
$abused_18_21=0;
$abused_22_24=0;

while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //count numbers of total abused per age group
    if ($rows["ageGroup"]=="6-8"){
        $abused_6_8+=$rows["totalAbused"];
    }
    if ($rows["ageGroup"]=="9-11"){
        $abused_9_11+=$rows["totalAbused"];
    }
    if ($rows["ageGroup"]=="12-14"){
        $abused_12_14+=$rows["totalAbused"];
    }
    if ($rows["ageGroup"]=="15-17"){
        $abused_15_17+=$rows["totalAbused"];
    }
    if ($rows["ageGroup"]=="18-21"){
        $abused_18_21+=$rows["totalAbused"];
    }
    if ($rows["ageGroup"]=="22-24"){
        $abused_22_24+=$rows["totalAbused"];
    }
}

/* Saving the data in the pData array >>it is a class created by pChart*/
$myData->addPoints(array($abused_6_8,$abused_9_11,$abused_12_14,$abused_15_17,$abused_18_21,$abused_22_24));
$myData->addPoints(array("6 - 8", "9 - 11","12 - 14","15 - 17","18 - 21","22 - 24"),"Age_Range");

/* Put the totalAbused column on the abscissa axis */
$myData->setAbscissa("Age_Range");

/* Create a pChart object and associate your dataset */
$myPicture = new pImage(700,300,$myData);

/* Draw the background */
```

$Settings = array("R"=>170, "G"=>183, "B"=>87, "Dash"=>1, "DashR"=>190, "DashG"=>203, "DashB"=>107);

$myPicture->drawFilledRectangle(0,0,700,300,$Settings); 
 $TextSettings = array("DrawBox"=>TRUE,"BoxRounded"=>TRUE,"R"=>130,"G"=>2,"B"=>2,"Angle"=>0,"FontName"=>"fonts/Bedizen.ttf", "FontSize"=>20);

$myPicture->drawText(250,30,"ABUSED PER AGE LEVEL",$TextSettings);

/* Overlay with a gradient */ 
 $Settings = array("StartR"=>219, "StartG"=>231, "StartB"=>139, "EndR"=>1, "EndG"=>138, "EndB"=>68, "Alpha"=>50); 
 $myPicture->drawGradientArea(0,0,700,300,DIRECTION_VERTICAL,$Settings);

/* Add a border to the picture */ 
 $myPicture->drawRectangle(0,0,699,299,array("R"=>0,"G"=>0,"B"=>0));

```
/* Choose a nice font */
$myPicture->setFontProperties(array("R"=>255,"G"=>255,"B"=>255,"FontName"=>"fonts/Forgotte.ttf","FontSize"=>16));

/* Define the boundaries of the graph area */
$myPicture->setGraphArea(60,40,670,270);

/* Draw the scale */ 
$scaleSettings = array("GridR"=>200,"GridG"=>200,"GridB"=>200,"DrawSubTicks"=>TRUE,"CycleBackground"=>TRUE); 
$myPicture->drawScale($scaleSettings); 

/* Turn on shadow computing */  
$myPicture->setShadow(TRUE,array("X"=>1,"Y"=>1,"R"=>0,"G"=>0,"B"=>0,"Alpha"=>10)); 

/* Create the per bar palette */
$Palette = array("0"=>array("R"=>188,"G"=>224,"B"=>46,"Alpha"=>100),
                "1"=>array("R"=>224,"G"=>100,"B"=>46,"Alpha"=>100),
                "2"=>array("R"=>255,"G"=>0,"B"=>255,"Alpha"=>100),
                "3"=>array("R"=>46,"G"=>151,"B"=>224,"Alpha"=>100),
                "4"=>array("R"=>109,"G"=>033,"B"=>24,"Alpha"=>100),
                "5"=>array("R"=>97,"G"=>0,"B"=>200,"Alpha"=>100),
                "6"=>array("R"=>0,"G"=>113,"B"=>63,"Alpha"=>100),
                "7"=>array("R"=>0,"G"=>145,"B"=>100,"Alpha"=>100));

/* Draw the chart */  
 $myPicture->drawBarChart(array("DisplayValues"=>TRUE,"Rounded"=>TRUE,"Surrounding"=>-30,"InnerSurrounding"=>30,"OverrideColors"=>$Palette)); 

/* Build the PNG file*/
$myPicture->Render("abusedPerBRGY.png");
//sending back the path to be used as src of #protBar image
echo "charts/abusedPerBRGY.png";
```

?>

I hope someone will response on this question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Help in what way? You haven't asked a question or told us you have errors.

Comment: Hi @JayBlanchard, I edited my inquiry. Hope I can get an answer on this. thanks!

Comment: Have you watched the console in the developer tools of the browser on the second click? Are there errors?

Comment: Yes, I did. There is no error seen in the developer tools. It seems that everything works fine except that the chart is not reloaded when i changed the search criteria.

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the developer tools - on the network tab?

Comment: [This may help, if it is a caching issue.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30654063/1011527)

Comment: Thanks @JayBlanchard, I got an answer on this already and posted my solution below. But I still appreciate your help. happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I really appreciate your help and it adds information to what I succeeded tonight(it's night here). I already got an answer to my problem. I just figured out that I need to set a blank src to my img every time the click event fires so that it's src becomes new since I am sending back the same src name in my protectionBar.php.

Please see my solution below.

```
 function subForm(){
    var id = $("#searcher").val();
    $('#protBar').attr('src', "#"); //this solved to what I needed.
    $.ajax({
        url: 'charts/protectionBar.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "html",
        data: { id: id },
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#protBar').attr('src', data);
        }
    })
```

}

But still, I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: Yes, it's the correct solution, because the image name does not change, so you need to _refresh_ it.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript function is not correct. If you use it on the `onclick` event it should look like this:

```
<script>
function subForm()
{
        var id = $("#searcher").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'charts/protectionBar.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "html",
            data: { id: id },
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#protBar').attr('src', data);

            }

        })
}
</script>
```

Comment: appreciate your help. I tried this, however, still the chart is not loaded after changing the search criteria via the search box and clicking the button at second attempt.

Comment: can you check your new id to see if it get's posted correct to the ajax call? `console.log(id)` right after you read it.

Comment: yes, it gets posted and it has the correct data. the only problem is the chart is not loading. :(

Comment: And, by the way, I checked also my script that processed the chart. The chart is processed correctly and the image is sent to the folder successfully.

Comment: Could you also post the important part of **protectionBar.php**? How does it return the data? What is posted back to the ajax call?

Comment: Hi @moni_dragu, I added my code in protectionBar.php above. thanks for extending your help here. hope we can work this out. Appreciate it much