# Ajax is refreshed php but not updated

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The information is not updated, or rather it refreshes, but it does not take out the new information. if I enter data.php, then if it takes out the new information, it's like it keeps the cache memory and doesn't get the new information added. After entering data.php, everything also appears in ajax.

data.php:

```
    <?php 
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxx', 'x', 'xx');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


        echo  
 " <tr>
    <td>".$row['username']."</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>";
    }
}
?>
```

ajax:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    ajax_call = function() {
        $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "GET",
            url: "data.php",
            dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
            success: function (response) {

                $("#responsecontainer").html(response);

            }
        });
    };
    var interval = 1000;
    setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
});
</script>
```

Edit: you change the data in ajax only if you manually enter data.php and then change it automatically in ajax page.

Comment: Could you provide console.log(response) here?

Comment: Check in the console (under Network tab) to see if the source of data.php is the same. If it is, you may need to add a random number to data.php in the ajax call (for example data.php?r=12345) or there may be other configuration you could set so that the cache expires immediately for requests to that page.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean, to be honest. Can you provide us with an actual example of the changes you expect to see in your data and HTML after running this code? The query just selects all users, so you will be likely to get the same result every time, unless someone has separately added and removed rows from that table. P.S. If caching is an issue, you can simply set `cache: false` in the $.ajax options

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30654063/1011527

Comment: you change the data in ajax only if you manually enter data.php and then change it automatically in ajax page

Comment: Is php7 use possible to influence this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only change GEt from POST and is work fine.